# Masstransit scoped filter using in retried messages

Tags: middleware, masstransit

We are trying to convert our code that works with `nservicebus` to masstransit. We had `middleware` on `Nsb`. Now I tried to use scoped filter in `Masstransit`.
I have 3 different filters (`IncomingMessageLoggerFilter ,ExceptionFilter,UnitOfWorkFilter`)

In the successful scenario, when I published the message, it first enters the filters in order (`IncomingMessageLoggerFilter -> ExceptionFilter -> UnitOfWorkFilter`), then it enters the consumer,
and then it ends by visiting the filters in the reverse order `(UnitOfWorkFilter -> ExceptionFilter -> IncomingMessageLoggerFilter`).
But in the scenario, where I throw an error in the consumer, it does not work as I want. I expect it to work in this order :

```
 publish message ->IncomingMessageLoggerFilter -> ExceptionFilter -> UnitOfWorkFilter -> Consumer(throw ex)-> ExceptionFilter(because of try catch in the this filter)->end
```

Repeat in the same order for retry requests (this is important I want my `middleware` to work in every cycle).

But in the new mass transit code order is different:

```
 publish message ->IncomingMessageLoggerFilter -> ExceptionFilter -> UnitOfWorkFilter -> Consumer(throw ex)-> consumer( retry attempt)->consumer ( retry attempt)--> ExceptionFilter(because of try catch in the this filter)->end
```

So the filters started and then the message came to the consumer. When I throw an error in the consumer, it will be retried again. I set retry 2 times in `masstransit` configuration on startup . When it retry message come, it goes to the consumer without going to the filter.

After 2 retry, flow returns to the `exceptionfilter`. In other words, the filters are visited at the beginning and at the end of. *What am I missing? How can I run it like in my old code ?*
**Startup**

```
          services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
               

                x.AddConsumer<SubmittedOrderNotificationEventConsumer>();
          
               
                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("guest");
                        h.Password("guest");
                    });

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(ExchangeMessageLibrary.EndpointNames.DemoService_EventQueueName, e =>
                    {
                     
                        e.ConfigureConsumer<SubmittedOrderNotificationEventConsumer>(context, c =>
                        {
                            
                            c.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)));
                         

                        });
                    });

                    cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(IncomingMessageLoggerFilter<>), context);
                    cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(ExceptionFilter<>), context);
                    cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(UnitOfWorkFilter<>), context);
                
                
                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);  
                });
            });
```

***Consumer***

```
 public class SubmittedOrderNotificationEventConsumer : IConsumer<OrderSubmittedEvent>
 {
     private readonly IBookOperations bookOperations;
     public SubmittedOrderNotificationEventConsumer( IBookOperations bookOperations)
     {
         this.bookOperations = bookOperations;

  
     }
     public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<OrderSubmittedEvent> context)
     {
         throw new BusinessException(NovaStatusCodes.NotFound, "Template.NotFound");

        
     }
 }
```

**Filters:**

*IncomingMessageLoggerFilter*

```
    public class IncomingMessageLoggerFilter<T> :
    IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>
    where T : class
    {
        private readonly IJsonSerializer jsonSerializer;
        private readonly INovaNsbLogger novaNsbLogger;
        CommonDataContext commonDataContext;
        public IncomingMessageLoggerFilter(INovaNsbLogger novaNsbLogger, CommonDataContext commonDataContext )
        {
            jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
            this.novaNsbLogger = novaNsbLogger;
            this.commonDataContext = commonDataContext;
        }

        public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
        {
           
            string messageName = context.Message?.GetType()?.Name;

            string message = jsonSerializer.SerializeWithoutFormat(context.Message);
            dynamic messageInstance = context.Message;

            #region MessageHeader to CommonDataContext

          

            commonDataContext.ServiceName = messageInstance?.NovaMessageHeader.SenderServiceName.ToString();
            commonDataContext.Channel = messageInstance?.NovaMessageHeader.Channel.ToString();
            commonDataContext.XCorrelationId = messageInstance?.NovaMessageHeader.XCorrelationId.ToString();
            commonDataContext.AcceptLanguage = messageInstance?.NovaMessageHeader.AcceptLanguage.ToString();
            commonDataContext.TenantId = Convert.ToInt32(messageInstance?.NovaMessageHeader.TenantId.ToString());
            commonDataContext.TriggeredBy = Convert.ToInt64(messageInstance?.NovaMessageHeader.TriggeredBy.ToString());
            commonDataContext.QueueMessageName = messageName;

            #endregion
            var payload = context.GetOrAddPayload(() => new SharedDataInContext
            {
                MessageId = context.MessageId.ToString(),
                MessageName = messageName,
                Message = message,
                NovaNsbLogger = this.novaNsbLogger,
                CommonDataContext = commonDataContext
            });
           
           

            #region Log

            var properties = new List<LogProperty>();

            properties.Add(new LogProperty()
            {
                Name = "date",
                Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff")
            });

            properties.Add(new LogProperty()
            {
                Name = "XCorrelationId",
                Value = commonDataContext.XCorrelationId
            });

            properties.Add(new LogProperty()
            {
                Name = "MessageId",
                Value = context.MessageId
            });

            properties.Add(new LogProperty()
            {
                Name = "MessageName",
                Value = messageName
            });

            properties.Add(new LogProperty()
            {
                Name = "Message",
                Value = message
            });

            novaNsbLogger.Log(new NovaLog(NovaLogLevel.Debug, "NServiceBusIncommingMessageLogger", properties));

            #endregion
            await next.Send(context);


        }

        public void Probe(ProbeContext context) { }
    }
```

*ExceptionFilter*

```
 public class ExceptionFilter<T> :
 IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>
 where T : class
 {
     private readonly NovaLocalization novaLocalization;
     public ExceptionFilter(NovaLocalization novaLocalization)
     {
         this.novaLocalization = novaLocalization;
     }

     public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
     {


         try
         {
             await next.Send(context);
         }
         catch (DoNotRetryException ex)
         {
             #region DoNotRetryException

             ConsoleHelper.WriteCommandLine("DoNotRetryException", ConsoleColor.Green);

             #region Log

             SharedDataInContext sharedDataInContext = context.GetPayload<SharedDataInContext>();

             var properties = new List<LogProperty>();

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "date",
                 Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff")
             });

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "XCorrelationId",
                 Value = sharedDataInContext.CommonDataContext.XCorrelationId
             });

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "MessageId",
                 Value = sharedDataInContext.MessageId
             });

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "MessageName",
                 Value = sharedDataInContext.MessageName
             });

             string logMessage = ex.sendErrorQueue == true ? "DoNotRetryException : Send Error Queue" : "DoNotRetryException : Without Send Error Queue";
             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "Exception",
                 Value = logMessage
             });

             #region DelayedRetryCount
             //if (context.Headers.TryGetHeader("MT-Redelivery-Count", out object retryCountObj) && retryCountObj is int retryCount)
                 
             bool isRetry = context.Headers.Any(x => x.Key == "MT-Redelivery-Count");
             int delayedRetryCount = 0;

             if (isRetry)
             {
                 context.Headers.TryGetHeader("MT-Redelivery-Count", out object retryCountObj);
                 delayedRetryCount = (int)retryCountObj;
                 //delayedRetryCount = Convert.ToInt32(context.MessageHeaders["NServiceBus.Retries"]);
             }
             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "DelayedRetryCount",
                 Value = delayedRetryCount
             });

             #endregion

             sharedDataInContext.NovaNsbLogger.Log(new NovaLog(NovaLogLevel.Debug, "NServiceBusBusinessExceptionLogger", properties));

             #endregion

             if (ex.sendErrorQueue)
             {
                 throw ex;
             }
             else
             {
                 //context.MessageHandled = true; //nsb
                 return;
             }

             #endregion
         }
         catch (BusinessException businessException)
         {
             SharedDataInContext sharedDataInContext = context.GetPayload<SharedDataInContext>();

             CommonDataContext commonDataContext = sharedDataInContext.CommonDataContext;

             #region Translation

             List<Error> translatedErrors = new List<Error>();

             if (businessException.iNeedTranslation)
             {
                 foreach (var error in businessException.Errors)
                 {
                     string translatedErrorMessage = novaLocalization.Get(error.code, commonDataContext.AcceptLanguage);

                     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(translatedErrorMessage))
                     {
                         translatedErrorMessage = "";
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         #region Replace Dynamic Parameters

                         if (businessException.parameters != null && businessException.parameters.Length > 0)
                         {
                             for (int i = 0; i < businessException.parameters.Length; i++)
                                 translatedErrorMessage = translatedErrorMessage.Replace("{" + i + "}", businessException.parameters[i]);
                         }

                         #endregion
                     }

                     translatedErrors.Add(new Error()
                     {
                         code = error.code,
                         description = translatedErrorMessage,
                         data = error.data
                     });
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 translatedErrors = businessException.Errors.Select(x => new Error() { code = x.code, description = x.description, data = x.data }).ToList();
             }

             #endregion

             #region Log

             var properties = new List<LogProperty>();

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "date",
                 Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff")
             });

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "XCorrelationId",
                 Value = sharedDataInContext.CommonDataContext.XCorrelationId
             });

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "MessageId",
                 Value = sharedDataInContext.MessageId
             });

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "MessageName",
                 Value = sharedDataInContext.MessageName
             });

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "Exception",
                 Value = new
                 {
                     StatusCode = businessException.StatusCode,
                     Errors = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(translatedErrors)
                 }
             });

             #region DelayedRetryCount
             var s=  context.Headers.Get(MessageHeaders.RedeliveryCount, default(int?));
             bool isRetry = context.Headers.Any(x => x.Key == "MT-Redelivery-Count");
             int delayedRetryCount = 0;

             if (isRetry)
             {
                 context.Headers.TryGetHeader("MT-Redelivery-Count", out object retryCountObj);
                 delayedRetryCount = (int)retryCountObj;
                 //delayedRetryCount = Convert.ToInt32(context.MessageHeaders["NServiceBus.Retries"]);
             }

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "DelayedRetryCount",
                 Value = delayedRetryCount
             });

             #endregion

             sharedDataInContext.NovaNsbLogger.Log(new NovaLog(NovaLogLevel.Debug, "NServiceBusBusinessExceptionLogger", properties));

             #endregion

             throw businessException;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             #region Log

             SharedDataInContext sharedDataInContext = context.GetPayload<SharedDataInContext>();

             var properties = new List<LogProperty>();

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "date",
                 Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff")
             });

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "XCorrelationId",
                 Value = sharedDataInContext.CommonDataContext.XCorrelationId
             });

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "MessageId",
                 Value = sharedDataInContext.MessageId
             });

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "MessageName",
                 Value = sharedDataInContext.MessageName
             });

             #region DelayedRetryCount

             bool isRetry = context.Headers.Any(x => x.Key == "MT-Redelivery-Count");
             int delayedRetryCount = 0;

             if (isRetry)
             {
                 context.Headers.TryGetHeader("MT-Redelivery-Count", out object retryCountObj);
                 delayedRetryCount = (int)retryCountObj;
                 //delayedRetryCount = Convert.ToInt32(context.MessageHeaders["NServiceBus.Retries"]);
             }

             properties.Add(new LogProperty()
             {
                 Name = "DelayedRetryCount",
                 Value = delayedRetryCount
             });

             #endregion

             sharedDataInContext.NovaNsbLogger.Log(new NovaLog(NovaLogLevel.Debug, "NServiceBusExceptionLogger", properties), ex);

             #endregion

             throw ex;
         }
     }

     public void Probe(ProbeContext context) { }
 }
```

*UnitOfWorkFilter*

```
    public class UnitOfWorkFilter<T> :
    IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>
    where T : class
    {
        IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public UnitOfWorkFilter(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) {
            _unitOfWork= unitOfWork;
         
        }

        public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
        {
            await next.Send(context);

            if (_unitOfWork != null)
                _unitOfWork.Commit(); 
        }

        public void Probe(ProbeContext context) { }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to MassTransit - if you need support migrating your code, you can contact [support](https://masstransit.io/support).